# Event Hub Triggers pushing same message to multiple app functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I've got a layout like this:

```
EventHubNameSpace
  HubA
  HubB
  HubC
```

Then I've got app functions:

```
Product
  .AppFunctions
    .FunctionA
    .FunctionB
    .FunctionC
```

FunctionA is supposed to be a trigger from HubA. (I've checked the Integrations Tab and that's the hub name I've got pointed to).

Same thing with FunctionB, to HubB, etc.

However, when something gets published to HubA, I see the message on FunctionB.  The question is why?

Is it that the event hub trigger is firing all of the functions under the "AppFunctions", when any event occurs at the hub namespace level?

They are all set to use $default as their consumer group, but I figured that would be at the event hub name level, not the event namespace level.

Do I need separate function apps, one for each event hub?

So what does has to change to have HubA's triggered messages only go to FunctionA?.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can repro the issue in my side. After some researching, I found the cause is that there is a redundant string `EntityPath` added to the [eventhub namespace connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string). Just remove this string then everything is ok.

The steps are as below:

1.Nav to azure portal, you azure function -> Configuration -> Application settings. Then click on the name of `yourEventhubNameSpace_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB`, remove the `EntityPath` from it. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Then click save button. After this changes, each function like FunctionA / FunctionB / FunctionC should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd set of eyes!   I totally missed it there.